# Disconnecting Azure Directory from Azure DevOps organization on Azure DevOps service portal creates login errors

Tags: azure-devops

I was playing around to learn the feature and concept on **Azure DevOps services**.
And I created one Azure DevOps Organization using my MSA account and connected it to my Azure Active Directory (as I have a pay-as-you-go subscription using my MSA account).

[image]

I then disconnected it from Azure Active Directory so it (forced) logged me out of the Azure DevOps portal. I was thinking that I will disconnect and connect it back to AAD. But apparently that's not how it works... and I found out in a very rude way.

After that I was **unable to login** to the Azure DevOps service portal using my MSA ID. And here is the error page:

[image]

I was able to somehow get over the issue by creating a new org using the organization list link provided on the error page.

> But now my question is, I do see my old DevOps Organization on Azure
>   DevOps Service portal which I am unable to access. Its sort of orphaned Org and just hanging there. **Now how do I get rid of
>   it or delete it?**

Answer (score 1):

what is happening is that azure devops is not able to sync up with your AAD. The reason it is showing "not authorized error" is because it can't identify whether the same tenant is  trying to connect(when you're logging in) to the project and the project is in the AAD parallely, so that is creating the miscommunication between your tenant, AAD and devops organisation.

Answer (score 0):

Sign out, and then open your browser in a private session and sign in to your organization with your Azure AD, MSA or work credentials.